# find duplicate element in array list

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class list {

protected ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

public boolean ad(String aa)
{ 
    boolean t=true;
    a.add(aa);

     for(String value : courses)
     {
            if(a.contains(value))
            {
             a=false;
            }
            else
            { 
                a=true;

            }
     }
    return a;

}

}
```

this program should return false if arraylist course contains duplicate elements.else if we are inserting new element return true.

expected output for above code is

```
true
```

but it only returns false for any condition.

Comment: Quick question about your requirement - what should be returned if the list contains a duplicate that's different from the element you're inserting?

Comment: it should return true in that case@DavidWallace

Comment: So all you need to do is use `contains` to check whether the list contains the element you're adding, right?  No need for a loop!  But it has to be _before_ you add the element, otherwise you'll just find the element itself.  Jacob G. has posted the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidWallace He said that 'it's not working with our code' which I don't believe.

Comment: Of course, OP's code mentions a class called `Instructor` (in `main`) but they've shown us a class called `list`.  I suspect OP is confused about which class is which, @JacobG.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Your code uses that Instructor class; and that one is completely **missing**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply utilize `ArrayList#contains` to verify if an element already exists within the `List`.

```
public boolean addCourse(String course) {
    if (courses.contains(course)) {
        return false;
    }

    return courses.add(course);
}
```

Comment: it should return true if we are inserting new element in arraylist.but its not working with our code @jacob G

Comment: @user7799918 That's exactly what this does.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding course in the list and then iterating thr the list, so it always gives you true. ArrayList allows duplicates.

```
 if(courses.contains(value))
```

will always return true as you are adding the course before this in arraylist.

Suggestion: You should use Set than list if you want to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ArrayList, how about using HashSet to keep your courses ?

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashset-class-in-java-with-example/

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class list {
  protected ArrayList<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
  protected String temp = "";

  public list(String str, String str2) {

  }

  public boolean addCourse(String course) {
    boolean a = true;
    if (courses.isEmpty()) {
        courses.add(course);
        temp = course;
    } else {
        if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(course)) {
            a = false;
            temp = "";
        } else {
            a = true;
            courses.add(course);
            temp = course;
        }
    }
    return a;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    list inst = new list("John", "WIU");
    System.out.println(inst.addCourse("CS560"));
    System.out.println(inst.addCourse("CS500"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Simple way you can do:***

**For Each time executing else block so. remove else block it will work.**

```
for(String value : courses)
 {
        if(courses.contains(value))
        {
         a=false;
         break;
        }

            a=true;

 }
```